# Elasticsearch Mapping for array

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have the following document for which I need to do mapping for elasticsearch

```json
"table_1": {
        "title": "Spine Imaging Guidelines",
        "rows": [
            "Procedure Codes Associated with Spine Imaging \n3",
            "SP-1: General Guidelines \n5",
            "SP-2: Imaging Techniques \n15",
            "SP-3: Neck (Cervical Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma \n24",
            "SP-4: Upper Back (Thoracic Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma \n28",
            "SP-5: Low Back (Lumbar Spine) Pain/Coccydynia without \nNeurological Features \n31",
            "SP-6: Lower Extremity Pain with Neurological Features \n(Radiculopathy, Radiculitis, or Plexopathy and Neuropathy) With or \nWithout Low Back (Lumbar Spine) Pain \n35",
            "SP-7: Myelopathy \n39",
            "SP-8: Lumbar Spine Spondylolysis/Spondylolisthesis \n42",
            "SP-9: Lumbar Spinal Stenosis \n45",
            "SP-10: Sacro-Iliac (SI) Joint Pain, Inflammatory \nSpondylitis/Sacroiliitis and Fibromyalgia \n47",
            "SP-11: Pathological Spinal Compression Fractures \n50",
            "SP-12: Spinal Pain in Cancer Patients \n52",
            "SP-13: Spinal Canal/Cord Disorders (e.g. Syringomyelia) \n53",
            "SP-14: Spinal Deformities (e.g. Scoliosis/Kyphosis) \n55",
            "SP-15: Post-Operative Spinal Disorders \n58",
            "SP-16: Other Imaging Studies and Procedures Related to the Spine \nImaging Guidelines \n61",
            "SP-17: Nuclear Medicine \n65"
        ],
        "meta": {
            "page_no": 2,
            "page_text": "Spine Imaging \nGuidelines\n Procedure Codes Associated with Spine Imaging\n 3 SP-1: General Guidelines\n 5 SP-2: Imaging Techniques\n 15 SP-3: Neck (Cervical Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma\n 24 SP-4: Upper Back (Thoracic Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma\n 28 SP-5: Low Back (Lumbar Spine) \nPain/Coccydynia without \nNeurological Features\n 31 SP-6: Lower Extremity Pain with Neurological Features \n(Radiculopathy, Radiculitis, or Plexopathy and Neuropathy) With or \nWithout Low Back (Lumba\nr Spine) Pain\n 35 SP-7: Myelopathy\n 39 SP-8: Lumbar Spine Spondylolysis/Spondylolisthesis\n 42 SP-9: Lumbar Spinal Stenosis\n 45 SP-10: Sacro\n-Iliac (SI) Joint Pain, Inflammatory \nSpondylitis/Sacroiliitis and Fibromyalgia\n 47 SP-11: Pathological Spinal Compression Fractures\n 50 SP-12: Spinal Pain in Cancer Patients\n 52 SP-13: Spinal Can\nal/Cord Disorders (e.g. Syringomyelia)\n 53 SP-14: Spinal Deformities (e.g. Scoliosis/Kyphosis)\n 55 SP-15: Post\n-Operative Spinal Diso\nrders\n 58 SP-16: Other Imaging Studies and Procedures Related to the Spine \nImaging Guidelines\n 61 SP-17: Nuclear Medicine\n 65    "
        }
    }
```

I am confused as to how can I map the "rows" as array is not supported in elasticsearch.

Comment: How do you use the data from rows?

Comment: Basically we will be querying guildelines in rows and returning revelant table data

Comment: Is it a term query? I think the ```rows: keyword``` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no need to specify any particular mapping for array values.**

If you will not define any explicit mapping, then the `rows` field will be dynamically added as of the `text` data type

There is no data type that is defined for [arrays in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html). You just need to make sure that the `rows` field contains the same type of data

---

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "rows": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "rows": "Myelopathy"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67581594",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.28976172,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Spine Imaging Guidelines",
          "rows": [
            "Procedure Codes Associated with Spine Imaging \n3",
            "SP-1: General Guidelines \n5",
            "SP-2: Imaging Techniques \n15",
            "SP-3: Neck (Cervical Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma \n24",
            "SP-4: Upper Back (Thoracic Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma \n28",
            "SP-5: Low Back (Lumbar Spine) Pain/Coccydynia without \nNeurological Features \n31",
            "SP-6: Lower Extremity Pain with Neurological Features \n(Radiculopathy, Radiculitis, or Plexopathy and Neuropathy) With or \nWithout Low Back (Lumbar Spine) Pain \n35",
            "SP-7: Myelopathy \n39",
            "SP-8: Lumbar Spine Spondylolysis/Spondylolisthesis \n42",
            "SP-9: Lumbar Spinal Stenosis \n45",
            "SP-10: Sacro-Iliac (SI) Joint Pain, Inflammatory \nSpondylitis/Sacroiliitis and Fibromyalgia \n47",
            "SP-11: Pathological Spinal Compression Fractures \n50",
            "SP-12: Spinal Pain in Cancer Patients \n52",
            "SP-13: Spinal Canal/Cord Disorders (e.g. Syringomyelia) \n53",
            "SP-14: Spinal Deformities (e.g. Scoliosis/Kyphosis) \n55",
            "SP-15: Post-Operative Spinal Disorders \n58",
            "SP-16: Other Imaging Studies and Procedures Related to the Spine \nImaging Guidelines \n61",
            "SP-17: Nuclear Medicine \n65"
          ],
          "meta": {
            "page_no": 2,
            "page_text": "Spine Imaging \nGuidelines\n Procedure Codes Associated with Spine Imaging\n 3 SP-1: General Guidelines\n 5 SP-2: Imaging Techniques\n 15 SP-3: Neck (Cervical Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma\n 24 SP-4: Upper Back (Thoracic Spine) Pain Without/With Neurological \nFeatures (Including Stenosis) and Trauma\n 28 SP-5: Low Back (Lumbar Spine) \nPain/Coccydynia without \nNeurological Features\n 31 SP-6: Lower Extremity Pain with Neurological Features \n(Radiculopathy, Radiculitis, or Plexopathy and Neuropathy) With or \nWithout Low Back (Lumba\nr Spine) Pain\n 35 SP-7: Myelopathy\n 39 SP-8: Lumbar Spine Spondylolysis/Spondylolisthesis\n 42 SP-9: Lumbar Spinal Stenosis\n 45 SP-10: Sacro\n-Iliac (SI) Joint Pain, Inflammatory \nSpondylitis/Sacroiliitis and Fibromyalgia\n 47 SP-11: Pathological Spinal Compression Fractures\n 50 SP-12: Spinal Pain in Cancer Patients\n 52 SP-13: Spinal Can\nal/Cord Disorders (e.g. Syringomyelia)\n 53 SP-14: Spinal Deformities (e.g. Scoliosis/Kyphosis)\n 55 SP-15: Post\n-Operative Spinal Diso\nrders\n 58 SP-16: Other Imaging Studies and Procedures Related to the Spine \nImaging Guidelines\n 61 SP-17: Nuclear Medicine\n 65    "
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Yash you will be querying like `"SP-1: General Guidelines \n5"` for this guideline in the row, and if this guideline is present in the row, then the document will be returned?

Comment: could be that or just a word from it like "Myelopathy"